# Is there a "Heap-use after free" in my code here?

Tags: c, malloc, hashtable

I have a struct in C which mimics a hashtable, except it is an array of linked lists.

The length of the array is predetermined by the `hash_length` and is set to `2^hash_length`.

My function here is supposed to free all of the memory allocated by its respective `ht_create` function. By looping through the array of linked lists, and freeing all of its nodes, and then freeing the array, followed by the hashtable itself.
Through running this code however, I am encountering a heap-use after free. I believe that the problem lies in the way I wrote the function itself but I cant seem to pinpoint the error. I am unsure whether this is enough information to determine a problem, let me know if there is further clarification needed.

```c
void ht_destroy(struct hashtable *ht) {
    for(int i = 0; i < my_exp(2,ht->hash_length); ++i) {
        struct llist *lst = &ht->list[i];
        struct llnode *curnode = lst->front;
        struct llnode *nextnode = NULL;
        while (curnode) {
            nextnode = curnode->next;
            free(curnode->str);
            free(curnode);
            curnode = nextnode;
        }
        free(&ht->list[i]);
    }
    free(ht->list);
    free(ht);
}
```

This should be a minimal reproducible example, one that simply creates a hashtable using `ht_create`, and then frees memory using `ht_destroy`

```
// my_exp(a,b): raises a to the bth power.
// Requires: b >= 0
int my_exp(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  int tot = a;
  for (int i = 1; i < b; ++i) {
    tot *= a;
  }

  return tot;
}

struct llnode {
  char *str;
  struct llnode *next;
};

struct llist {
  struct llnode *front;
};

struct hashtable {
  int hash_length;
  struct llist *list;
};

struct hashtable *ht_create(int hash_length) {

  struct hashtable *ht = malloc(sizeof(struct hashtable));

  ht->list = malloc(my_exp(2,hash_length) * sizeof(struct llist));
  ht->hash_length = hash_length;

  for(int i = 0; i < my_exp(2,hash_length); ++i ){
    (ht->list)[i].front = NULL;
  }
  return ht;
}

void ht_destroy(struct hashtable *ht) {
  for(int i = 0; i < my_exp(2,ht->hash_length); ++i) {
      struct llist *lst = &ht->list[i];
      struct llnode *curnode = lst->front;
      struct llnode *nextnode = NULL;
      while (curnode) {
        nextnode = curnode->next;
        free(curnode->str);
        free(curnode);
        curnode = nextnode;
      }
  free(&ht->list[i]);
  }
free(ht->list);
free(ht);
}

int main(void) {
struct hashtable *ht = ht_create(2);
ht_destroy(ht);
}
```

Comment: It will help if you can create a [mre]: a small but complete program that we can run to see the problem ourselves.

Comment: `&ht->list[i]` seems like it should be `ht->list[i]`.

Comment: @Barmar making that change results in the error: passing 'struct llist' to parameter of incompatible type 'void *'

Comment: `ht->list[i]` is an array element, its address can't be a value returned by `malloc()`, so you can't free it.

Comment: Get rid of this line: `free(&ht->list[i]);`. It's trying to free something that wasn't allocated. Which `malloc()` in `ht_create()` do you think it corresponds to?

Comment: @Barmar Ah, so the while loop already frees all of the memory inside of each linked list, so it wouldn't make sense to free it again. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is causing undefined behavior:

```
        free(&ht->list[i]);
```

`ht->list[i]` is an array element. The array `ht->list` was allocated dynamically, but the addresses of its individual elements were not, so you can't free them. The dynamically-allocated elements are in the linked list reached from `ht->list[i].head`, and you freed them in the `while` loop.

The "use after free" is because `&ht->list[0]` is equivalent to `ht->list`, so the first iteration of the `for` loop is freeing the entire array, then subsequent iterations try to use elements of that freed array. And you then try to free it again with `free(ht->list)`.

Get rid of the above line.